# Convert a JSON to CSV in Node JS

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, json2csv

I am starting to study `Node JS` and I am trying to convert an external `JSON` file to CSV format.

The operation that I am trying to achieve is the following: in an internal file I have two urls that lead to an external JSON each (api1 and api2), given the url `http://localhost:3000/?api=api1`, you have to download the `JSON` of the `api1` in CSV format with a maximum of 50 lines.

This is the code I have so far (I have added some modules that I have seen are necessary):

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

const converter = require("json-2-csv");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fs = require("fs");
const flatten = require('flat');

const conf = require(`../conf/${process.env.NODE_ENV}.json`);
const maxRecords = 50;

class IndexController {
  public async index(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const api =req.query.api; //api1
    const url = conf.API_MOCS[`${api}`].url; //https://mock.com/api1

    const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
    path: 'path/to/file.csv',
    header: [
        {id: 'index', title: 'Index'},
        {id: 'index_start_at', title: 'Index start'},
        {id: 'integer', title: 'Integer'},
        {id: 'float', title: 'Float'},
        {id: 'name', title: 'Name'}
    ]
});

fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => csvWriter.writeRecords(json.myItems));
  }
}
export const indexController = new IndexController();
```

This is my internal file that contains the url of the JSON:

```
{
  "API_MOCS": {
    "api1": {
      "url": "https://mock.com/api1"
    },
    "api2": {
      "url": "https://mock.com/api2"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first ‘fetch’ the json from the URL. There are plenty of libraries available to help you with this. Take a look at:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch
Or https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Then you can write the CSV file. I’d recommend using a library for that too. First hit: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-writer

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;

const conf = require(`../conf/${process.env.NODE_ENV}.json`);
const maxRecords = 50;

class IndexController {
  public async index(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const api =req.query.api; //api1
    const url = conf.API_MOCS[`${api}`].url; //https://mock.com/api1
    const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
      path: 'path/to/file.csv',
      header: [
        {id: 'name', title: 'NAME'},
        {id: 'lang', title: 'LANGUAGE'}
      ]
    });

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => csvWriter.writeRecords(json.myItems));
  }
}
export const indexController = new IndexController();
```

Comment: Yes, I have installed the node-fetch and fs modules as I put in the question. My problem is that I don't know how to follow, how can I read the JSON and download it in CSV format?

Comment: I’ve added an example for you

Comment: It shows me the following error: ``TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object``. I have updated the question

Comment: +1 for suggesting  a fully-debugged library for CSV handling. CSV looks simple, but it has many little quirks, and there's not much value to be had from rediscovering them.

Comment: Are you getting this TypeError  in the csv-writer module or before that? It is hard to reproduce without having an example output of the API's. Could you provide that?

Comment: I have updated with the current code. I am testing with the ``json-2-csv`` module and I have created a method to read the information from the JSON but I cannot download it in CSV

Comment: I have tried with createCsvWriter but it shows me two errors in fetch: Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type and Parameter 'json' implicitly has an 'any' type